# javascript prototype extending deleteting child functions

Tags: javascript

```
function extend(Child, Parent){
    var F = function() { }
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype
    Child.prototype = new F()
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child
    Child.superclass = Parent.prototype
}
```

I have a problem, when extending the parent class the children prototype functions are being deleted, how to save the children functions and extend the parent using this function?

Comment: I believe you're profoundly confused on the nature of prototype.
Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work
It will help you start unwinding the mess you have in your question.

Comment: it looks like I can extend using this function only one time, because the prototype overwrites all the data in the children prototype

Comment: prototype doesn't work the way you think it works. Please familiarize yourself with how to use it.  Notice how in the example I link to, no one is assigning anything TO prototype. That's because that's not what it's there for.  `Child.prototype = new Foo()` is a horrible mistake.

Comment: Why shouldn't you assign to `prototype`? How else would you achieve prototype chaining?

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like that then you would add the properties of the child prototype afterwards.

```
function MyChild() {}
extend(MyChild, MyParent);

MyChild.prototype.newMethod = function () {}
```

I suggest using [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) or a [sham](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim).